# Saving editor layout

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, editor

I'd like to save my VSC's layout with certain files open in separate editor groups. For example:

```
Left Group --- Right Group

Config1          Script1

Config2          Script2
```

I've tried this extension: https://github.com/ctf0/vscode-save-editor-layout -- but it's broken for me and reports every tab I try to save as a 'temporary unsaved tab' that cannot be saved. I guess I could never close my editor, but I'd rather not. I've been thinking of some way to automate the resizing/splitting of my tabs but was wondering if there's an easier way I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows, the author fixed an issue.
It's working now.
https://github.com/ctf0/vscode-save-editor-layout/issues/1

Comment: @ThingsAreBroken Please vote in my answer so other people can enjoy this extension. And mark the answer as correct (the green check image). Thanks.